# Async Java method for Azure Function App?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I am currently working on creating the EventhubTriggered Java function app which listenes to the default-endpoint of the IotHub.  Currently following the tutorials,  I donot see any sample codes for Async implementation for Java Function Apps while it is recommended to use async/await for C# function apps.

Should I consider/ is it possible to add Async implementation for Function Apps in Java? Is there any sample code I can take a reference from? Should I consider adding parallel programming/Multithreading logic in the function app?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=java#example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.eventhubtrigger?view=azure-java-stable

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have async/await but it has [reactive/webflux](https://projectreactor.io/).

When you create default project azure function it should be packaged with reactive so you just need to make your calls in reactive way.

So lets say if you want to do some call to external sources your code will look like

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<WishlistDto>> getList(String profileId, String listId) {
    return service.getWishList(profileId, listId)
            .map(w -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(DtoMapper.convertToDto(w, true)))
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

But I would recommend you to use [input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=java)/output bindings as much as you can

```
 @FunctionName("DocByIdFromQueryString")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req",
              methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
              authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @CosmosDBInput(name = "database",
              databaseName = "ToDoList",
              collectionName = "Items",
              id = "{Query.id}",
              partitionKey = "{Query.partitionKeyValue}",
              connectionStringSetting = "Cosmos_DB_Connection_String")
            Optional<String> item,
            final ExecutionContext context)
```

In this case you dont need to worry much about reactive since your function starts as soon as every thing is ready and java sdk will take care of it

Another example to use [output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=java)

```
@FunctionName("sbtopicsend")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @ServiceBusTopicOutput(name = "message", topicName = "mytopicname", subscriptionName = "mysubscription", connection = "ServiceBusConnection") OutputBinding<String> message,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        
        String name = request.getBody().orElse("Azure Functions");

        message.setValue(name);
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using the EventHubTrigger input binding in the function app. The app gets the eventhubmessage(JsonArray) parses the message, loops through the array and makes the HTTPUrlConnection to make a POST  Call to another endpoint passing the JsonObject from the eventhubmessage as a Request Body. I am using Gson Library to parse the eventhubmessage. Do I need to consider anything for the Parallel programming /Concurrency for this?

Comment: Also, should I use concurrenthashmap in the function app?

Comment: @Jasmine are you using spring cloud function or just  azure functions?

Comment: Just Azure functions. I am using azure-functions-archtype to create this function.

Comment: @Jasmine As I understand you wont be able to do this this way. I would have a look into Spring boot Cloud Functions. I found https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/244 open ticket this would probably fix your problem but it still open.

Answer (score 0):

I release a new project [JAsync](https://github.com/vipcxj/jasync) implement async-await fashion in java which use Reactor as its low level framework. It is in the alpha stage.  I need more suggest and test case.
This project makes the developer's asynchronous programming experience as close as possible to the usual synchronous programming, including both coding and debugging.

Here is an example:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class MyRestController {
    @Inject
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @Inject
    private SalaryRepository salaryRepository;

    // The standard JAsync async method must be annotated with the Async annotation, and return a JPromise object.
    @Async()
    private JPromise<Double> _getEmployeeTotalSalaryByDepartment(String department) {
        double money = 0.0;
        // A Mono object can be transformed to the JPromise object. So we get a Mono object first.
        Mono<List<Employee>> empsMono = employeeRepository.findEmployeeByDepartment(department);
        // Transformed the Mono object to the JPromise object.
        JPromise<List<Employee>> empsPromise = Promises.from(empsMono);
        // Use await just like es and c# to get the value of the JPromise without blocking the current thread.
        for (Employee employee : empsPromise.await()) {
            // The method findSalaryByEmployee also return a Mono object. We transform it to the JPromise just like above. And then await to get the result.
            Salary salary = Promises.from(salaryRepository.findSalaryByEmployee(employee.id)).await();
            money += salary.total;
        }
        // The async method must return a JPromise object, so we use just method to wrap the result to a JPromise.
        return JAsync.just(money);
    }

    // This is a normal webflux method.
    @GetMapping("/{department}/salary")
    public Mono<Double> getEmployeeTotalSalaryByDepartment(@PathVariable String department) { 
        // Use unwrap method to transform the JPromise object back to the Mono object.
        return _getEmployeeTotalSalaryByDepartment(department).unwrap(Mono.class);
    }
}
```

In addition to coding, JAsync also greatly improves the debugging experience of async code.
When debugging, you can see all variables in the monitor window just like when debugging normal code.

[image: 98G39DXNF)ZI_C7`AP{7JZC]