# Azure Function - Convert synchronous to asynchronous

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure Function written in Java which at the moment does't do much but works synchronously.

I need to convert this to an asynch pattern but can't find a way. Can someone help with how I might convert this to asynch to have it return immediately but do all the work in the background?

thanks

```
@FunctionName("StaticWebPage")
public HttpResponseMessage getStaticWebPage(
    @HttpTrigger(
        name = "req",
        methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
        authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
    HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
    final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    File htmlFile = new File("index.html");
    try{
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(htmlFile.toPath());
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(fileContent).build();
    }catch (Exception e){
        context.getLogger().info("Error reading file.");
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to convert your code from synchronous to asynchronous you can refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/async-programming#reactive-streams) which includes CompletableFuture library  which uses reactive-streams and this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914819/async-java-method-for-azure-function-app#) answer by **Vova Bilyachat** which uses reactive.
>
> I have created the Azure Function Default HTTP Trigger by referring this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash,consumption#triggers-and-annotations) and this [Blog](https://quarkus.io/guides/azure-functions)
>
> **Default Code below:-**
>
> ```java
>  @HttpTrigger(name  =  "req",  methods  = {
> HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST },  authLevel  =
> AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)  HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>>
> request, final  ExecutionContext context) {
> context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
> ```

***Function.JAVA Code :-***

```java
import java.util.Optional;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.io.File;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

  

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;

  

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

  
  

public  class  Function {

@FunctionName("StaticWebPage")

public  CompletableFuture<HttpResponseMessage> getStaticWebPageAsync(

@HttpTrigger(name  =  "req",  methods  = { HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST },  authLevel  = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)  HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,

final  ExecutionContext context) {

  

context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

  

CompletableFuture<byte[]> fileContentFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

File htmlFile = new  File("index.html");

try {

Path path = Paths.get(htmlFile.toURI());

return Files.readAllBytes(path);

} catch (Exception e) {

throw  new  RuntimeException(e);

}

});

  

return fileContentFuture.thenApply(fileContent -> {

return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(fileContent).build();

}).exceptionally(ex -> {

context.getLogger().log(Level.WARNING,  "Error reading file.", ex);

return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();

});

}

}
```

**Output:-**

**Function got triggered successfully like below:-**

[image]