# How do You create reactive Azure app function with java 17 & spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure 4.x.x?

Tags: java, azure, cloud, project-reactor, reactive

Currently i have bunch of Azure app function using java 11 and azure runtime 3 and I want to migrate them to runtime 4, so I thought I will also upgrade the java and other libs. But it tured out to be problematic to stay reactive approach. So now most of the functions are triggered with org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker which looks like this:

```
public class SomeFunction extends FunctionInvoker<String, String>
{
    @FunctionName("someFuction")
    public HttpResponseMessage execute(
            @HttpTrigger(
                    name = "someFunction",
                    methods = {HttpMethod.POST},
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION,
                    route = "someFunction")
                    HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context)
    {
        Object body;
        HttpStatus status;

        try
        {
            var requestBody = request.getBody().orElseThrow(() -> new MessagingException(EMPTY_BODY));

            var result = ofNullable(handleRequest(requestBody, context))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(UNEXPECTED_ERROR));

            return request
                    .createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .body(result)
                    .build();
        }
        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            status = BAD_REQUEST;
            body = createErrorResponseBody(getPath(request), status.value(), e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            status = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            body = createErrorResponseBody(getPath(request), status.value(), e.getMessage());
        }

        return request
                .createResponseBuilder(status)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .body(body)
                .build();
    }
}
```

With new versions the FunctionInvoker is deprecated and should be replaced with  AzureFunctionInstanceInjector so I've tried to modify the example from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/tree/dev/samples/spring-cloud-example) to work with reactor as all my functions look like this Function<Mono, Mono> but it looks like the function is not automaticly subscibed on and returns the Mono object as response to API call. And if function returns CompletableFuture intead of Mono it fails with Gson [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76060705/azure-function-convert-synchronous-to-asynchronous)

New Impl I came up with looks like this:

```
@Component
public class UppercaseHandlerMono {

    @Autowired
    private Function<Mono<String>, Mono<String>> uppercaseMono;

    @FunctionName("uppercaseMono")
    public Mono<String> execute(
        @HttpTrigger(
            name = "req",
            methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().warning("Using Java (" + System.getProperty("java.version") + ")");
        return Mono.just(request)
                .map(r -> r.getBody().orElse(""))
                .flatMap(r -> uppercaseMono.apply(Mono.just(r)));
    }
}
```

Here is the reproduced [code](https://github.com/durtrim/azure-example).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I don't want to use .block in the invoker ;/

Sample response when function returns Mono:

```
{
  "mapper": {},
  "optimizableOperator": {},
  "source": {}
}
```

Sample Gson error when function returns CompletableFuture:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.uppercase. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field volatile java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.result accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent" to unnamed module @17d10166
Stack: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture#result' accessible; either change its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type
```

Key points from pom:

```
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

TLDR: I want to create reactive azure app function with reactor so i can return Mono<?> without blocking.